# Find any keyword entered into Search input on lengthy HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I looked online for a few references to my question, but having a hard time understanding what it is I truly need to do to make this work.

For example, if I want to search for the keyword "necessary" or any keyword I need to find, how would I go about finding that keyword using a Input search field throughout all the text in the page and go down to that keyword?

Would this require some JavaScript?

For reference, I provided some basic HTML code i'm trying to filter through and the word necessary is toward the bottom...

Any ideas would help!

```html
  <div class="course-title">
    <h4>Difficult Conversations: Situation, Behavior, Impact</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="course-info">
    <p><span>Course Description:</span> The Situation/Behavior/Impact model is perfect to prepare feedback statements when it’s critical to give clear, actionable feedback. Learn more about the model, how to use, and how to manage through complicated conversations.
    </p>
    <p><span>Subject:</span> Personal Growth</p>
    <p><span>Provider:</span>L&D</p>
    <p><span>Timing:</span> 1.5 Hours</p>
    <p><span>Formats Offered:</span> Virtual</p>
    <p><span>Link:</span> <a href="#"></a></p>
  </div>

  <br><br>
  <div class="course-title">
    <h4>Leading Change</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="course-info">
    <p><span>Course Description:</span> Change is a constant in innovative organizations, so it’s imperative to handle it well and adapt. In this workshop, discover what happens neurologically when change is experienced, and learn easy techniques to reduce resistance and increase inspiration, commitment, and decisive action.
    </p>
    <p><span>Course Type:</span> Leadership Development</p>
    <p><span>Provider:</span> LL</p>
    <p><span>Timing:</span> 2 Hours</p>
    <p><span>Formats Offered:</span> Virtual</p>
    <p><span>Accessing:</span> <a href="#"></a></p>
  </div>

  <br><br>
  <div class="course-title">
    <h4>Managing Difficult Conversations: Issue Clearing</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="course-info">
    <p><span>Course Description:</span> Difficult conversations are a common and necessary aspect in growing a strong, connected team with a high trust climate. In this session, we'll explore Issue Clearing, a tool to help guide conversations towards open, clear, vulnerable communication.
    </p>
    <p><span>Course Type:</span> Leadership Development</p>
    <p><span>Provider:</span> L&D</p>
    <p><span>Timing:</span> 2 Hours</p>
    <p><span>Formats Offered:</span> Virtual</p>
    <p><span>Accessing:</span> <a href="#"></a></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to go down? How about displaying only the courses with the tag the user enters? If it is necessary, you can add a special id and then to show that id at the top, you can go to `<url>#<id>`.

Comment: I actually found this solution! http://help.dottoro.com/ljkjvqqo.php

Answer (score 0):

You could give each section its' own anchor. for example by changing each `h4` (such as this one):

```
<div class="course-title">
  <h4>Managing Difficult Conversations: Issue Clearing</h4>
</div>
```

to:

```
<a name="courseid123456">
  <div class="course-title">
    <h4>Managing Difficult Conversations: Issue Clearing</h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

then you can jump to that location either with hyperlinks (`<a href="#courseid123456"></a>`) or with javascript code such as `window.location = '#courseid123456';`

Comment: I actually ended up finding a solution! You can view the example here incase you'd like to use it for your own wesbites. http://help.dottoro.com/ljkjvqqo.php